Is there a way to check if a Window (by its handle) is present in the Task Bar?
I need to know whether or not a UserForm of which I know the Handle has been added to the Task Bar.
There is a subject that seems to address the same issue but I don't understand what is its outcome.
Would this code be fine in 32bits & 64bits ?
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
#End If

'Window field offsets for GetWindowLong() or SetWindowLong()
Private Const GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8)
Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)

'Extended Window Style
Private Const WS_EX_APPWINDOW = &H40000
Private Const WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = &H80

Function IsUserFormInTaksBar(UserFormHandle As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim iStyle As Variant

    iStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(UserFormHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    IsUserFormInTaksBar = CBool(iStyle And WS_EX_APPWINDOW)
End Function

It seems to work for a UserForm but it's not at all a mask that would indicate that a Window is present in the Task Bar.
The mission of getting a list of Task Bar Windows is really impossible !

but I don't understand what is its outcome - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550378/get-a-list-of-apps-or-windows-currently-visible-in-the-windows-task-bar#comment119093240_8550378 -> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar.
